# using SOAP web service for implementing login for iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, web-services, soap, nsmutableurlrequest

it will be greatful  if you help me with this issue, i am a beginner on this platform and this is the first time am using SOAP service. , and i need to implement a login page. i don't know how to use the datas from the service.

```
POST /soap.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.bids4all.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.bids4all.com/Login"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://www.bids4all.com" xmlns:types="http://www.bids4all.com/encodedTypes"   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <tns:Login>
     <Email xsi:type="xsd:string">string</Email>
     <Password xsi:type="xsd:string">string</Password>
    </tns:Login>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://www.bids4all.com" xmlns:types="http://www.bids4all.com/encodedTypes" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <tns:LoginResponse>
      <LoginResult xsi:type="xsd:boolean">boolean</LoginResult>
    </tns:LoginResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

will you please help me with some cods? thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 good tools to generate SOAP client for iOS. They are [SudzC](http://sudzc.com/) and [wsdl2objc project](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/). Both of them supply example codes.

You can either use one of them or generate your own request and post it by NSURLConnection.

Hope it helps...

Comment: okay, thanks for ur replay , i used SudzC and gave my web service http://www.bids4all.com/soap.asmx. some source code is downloaded at that time. sorry, i don't know how to use those files. which file is useful for my requirement?

Comment: Try to watch the video in the SudcZ homepage. There are some tutorials about including the sources and using them in the archive that you have downloaded. I think, both of them are very similar as usage. You should try them and decide.

Comment: yes i tried the first method and pass the values for email, password and token. but it returns the value <ArrayOfProduct></ArrayOfProduct>, it suppose to return YES or NO. what should i do with this?

Comment: @NeerajNeeru It seems that your service doesn't return such value for login call. I think, you are calling another service method..